# Pipe grep output into sed to replace an entire line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to pipe the output of a grep command into the 'replace me with' value in a sed command. I've tried xargs and just a pipe, but I can't seem to get it working. All of the examples I've found on stack overflow assume that I know the end result of my grep command. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network | grep HOSTNAME | grep -i s/greppedline/"HOSTNAME=something"/
```

Effectively, I won't know the full contents of the line that I need to replace, just the fact that HOSTNAME will be in it. Is there a away to do this as a one-liner without creating a variable from the grep commmand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do like this,

```
sed '/HOSTNAME/s/.*/"HOSTNAME=something"/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Add the inline edit `-i` option to save the changes made.

```
sed -i.bak '/HOSTNAME/s/.*/"HOSTNAME=something"/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't even realize I could use a wildcard with sed. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/HOSTNAME/ c\
"HOSTNAME=something"/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

or

```
sed 's/.*HOSTNAME.*/"HOSTNAME=something"/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```